# Limiting number of decimal digits in ArcGIS to have exported file in CAD with same format?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, autocad, microstation, decimal-points

I am supposed to have some numeric values in ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop with 3 decimals Digits and then convert them to Microstation or AutoCAD. I did this Setting using field calculator and 'round' function in ArcGIS but when I convert it to CAD again it would come with more than 10 decimals which is not desired.

Comment: Can you not set this in the CAD software?

Comment: How are you exporting? what data type are you exporting from? where are you using it in cad? as a label/annotation? in a table? the other thing to try is to set the field property in arcmap, and then do your export.

Comment: I Export using data interopeability, the data types are shapefiles, I use the converted in AutoCAD ad MStation.

Answer (score 2):

After you round the values, you could create a new field and make sure to set the scale to 3 and calculate the values over.

Check out the **ArcGIS 10.2 Online Help** for **[Add Field](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000047000000)**:

> **field_scale**
>
> Sets the number of decimal places stored in a field. This parameter is
>   only used in Float and Double data field types.
>
> **If the input table is a personal or file geodatabase the field scale value will be ignored.**

Comment: Well, actually I have tried your affer as well but it does not work since it is Kind of just visual and not real. Also, in FGBD you can not Limit it so I have exported to shape file and add the new field with Limit 3 Digits but when gaon Comes to FGDB still would with more that 3 Digits.

Comment: My only other suggestion would be to ask on the Autodesk CAD forums and see if they have a recommendation. It may be something you can change on the CAD side http://forums.autodesk.com/